# How do I add a limit to the input in a showInputDialog in Java

Tags: java, input, dialog

I am very new to Java and I want to add a limit to how many characters a player of my game can enter in the JOptionPane.showInputDialog when the player has gotten a score that is in the top 10 highscores. I would like the limit to the input to be 5 characters. The code that I have for this piece of the game is this:

```
        // checkTop10Highscore returns a position of the highscore in the top 10, or -1 if the score of the player
        // is not in the top 10 highscores.
        // This is chosen instead of a boolean to prevent an extra database call after knowing it is in the top 10 to
        // know where it is in the top 10 - this is now done in one call.
        // playerCar.getScore() -- put in args below when finished testing
        int posInTop10 = PlayerHighscoreCheck.checkTop10Highscore(playerCar.getScore());

        if (posInTop10 == -1 && !this.renderedOnce) { // posInTop10 == -1 for testing dialog screen, != for normal gameplay
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("InputDialog PlayerName");

            // Prompt the player to enter their name
            String playerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                    (frame, "Congratulations, your score is in the top 10! Enter your name here.");

            // Get the user's input. Note that if they press Cancel, 'name' will be null
            System.out.printf("The user's name is '%s'.\n", playerName);
            if (playerName == null) {
                playerName = "UNKWN";
            }
            // Save the input as playerName
            // Use the playerName in the database

            if(playerName.length() <= 5) {
                PlayerHighscoreCheck.savePlayerNameInTop10(playerName, playerCar.getScore(), posInTop10);
                renderedOnce = true;
                System.out.print("Saved name + score in database \n");
            } else {
                JFrame frameMaxChars = new JFrame("InputDialog PlayerName");

                // Prompt the player to enter their name
                String playerNameMax5Chars = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                        (frame, "Your name can be a maximum of 5 characters");

                System.out.printf("The user's name is '%s'.\n", playerNameMax5Chars);
                // String playerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Your name can be a maximum of 5 characters!");
                // System.out.print("Your name can be a maximum of 5 characters");

                if (playerNameMax5Chars.length() <= 5) {
                    PlayerHighscoreCheck.savePlayerNameInTop10(playerNameMax5Chars, playerCar.getScore(), posInTop10);
                    renderedOnce = true;
                    System.out.print("Saved name + score in database \n");
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to get rid of the bottom if-statement by adding a limit to the amount of characters a player can input in the input dialog. I cannot find any solutions to this online, and I would love to make this piece of code a bit better to read.

Thank you loads in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JOptionPane’s input field doesn’t provide that capability, but you can give it your own JTextField, which you must configure in advance to allow only five characters.

A JOptionPane’s message doesn’t have to be a string.  As [the documentation states](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html), it can be an AWT or Swing component, in which case the component itself is displayed as the message.  Also permitted is an array, which itself can contain strings and/or components.  You can use this to your advantage to pass your own input field in place of the default one.

Instead of showInputDialog, you want to call [showOptionDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog%28java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,int,int,javax.swing.Icon,java.lang.Object[],java.lang.Object%29), which will not show an internally created input field, only your own custom message which contains your customized JTextField.

As for the customization to allow only five characters, you must create a custom [Document](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/Document.html) and [set a DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/AbstractDocument.html#setDocumentFilter%28javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter%29) on it.  Your custom DocumentFilter must override the `insertString` and `replace` methods to limit the overall length of the document.

Putting it all together looks like this:

```
int maxLength = 5;

JTextField nameField = new JTextField(maxLength);

PlainDocument doc = new PlainDocument();
doc.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass bypass,
                             int offset,
                             String text,
                             AttributeSet attr)
    throws BadLocationException {
        int newLength =
            bypass.getDocument().getLength() + text.length();
        if (newLength <= maxLength) {
            super.insertString(bypass, offset, text, attr);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass bypass,
                        int offset,
                        int length,
                        String text,
                        AttributeSet attr)
    throws BadLocationException {
        int newLength =
            bypass.getDocument().getLength() - length + text.length();
        if (newLength <= maxLength) {
            super.replace(bypass, offset, length, text, attr);
        }
    }
});
nameField.setDocument(doc);

int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame, new Object[] {
        "Congratulations, your score is in the top 10! Enter your name here.",
        nameField
    },
    "High Scorer",
    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
    null, null, null);

String playerName =
    (response == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION ? nameField.getText() : null);
```